# how to show image within another image on map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to show image within another image on map.

like

[image]

Here red colored image is different Image and the black idol image one is different .

Comment: Have you tried using `Frame Layout` for this?I think it works but not sure that whether its the correct way or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public Bitmap mergeBitmaps(Bitmap manBitmap){

    try{
        Bitmap markerBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( this.getResources(), R.drawable.red_box_image);
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(markerBitmap.getWidth(), markerBitmap.getHeight(), markerBitmap.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(markerBitmap, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(manBitmap, 5, 5, null);
        return bmOverlay;
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Umesh it is exactly I wanted.