# How to Overlay a image on top of another image dynamically in android?

Tags: java, android

How can i overlay two images (transparently) using Java libraries or existing android libraries

Comment: Checkout my answer in the following link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351998/how-to-show-image-within-another-image-on-map-in-android/8352029#8352029

Comment: Here is a similar question ..refer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459450/android-dynamic-transparent-image-overlay